# c# WPF get value of multiselected row of listview

Tags: c#, listview

Im using this code but it return System.Data.DataRowView instead of column  value of multiselected row

```
foreach (var item in myListView.SelectedItems)
{
    //do something with the values, maybe add to a list?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach (var item in myListView.SelectedItems)
{
    DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)item ;
   var sValue = dr.Row["columnName"] as string;
}
```